# How to solve GpuAcc_64.dll exception in OpenCV 3 and C++?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I get Exception thrown at 0x..... (GpuAcc_64.dll) when I try to use a uEye camera in C++ (OpenCV 3). Any idea how to solve this? This happens at code line "VideoCapture capture = VideoCapture(1);"

**My Code:**

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // The number of boards you want to capture, the number of internal corners horizontally 
    // and the number of internal corners vertically (That's just how the algorithm works). 
    int numBoards;
    int numCornersHor;
    int numCornersVer;

    cout << "Enter number of corners along width: ";
    cin >> numCornersHor;

    cout << "Enter number of corners along height: ";
    cin >> numCornersVer;

    cout << "Enter number of boards: ";
    cin >> numBoards;

    // We also create some additional variables that we'll be using later on. 
    int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
    Size board_sz = Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

    // We want live feed for our calibration! 
    VideoCapture capture = VideoCapture(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a laptop with a dedicated and on-board GPU, try disabling one of them and see if that works.

I don't know exactly what causes the issue but this is what solved the issue for me. (more specifically, disabling my on-board GPU fixed it)